# Difference between reading a directory(readdir) and a lookup operation on the directory

Tags: linux, filesystems

Would be very gratefull to know about how the operations, reading  directory say using readdir() different from a directory lookup performed while resolving a path to a file/directory. How different are they in the logic of their implementation? Will higly appreciate any references to literature too.

I am also not knowing exactly how to find out how atomicity of filesystem operations are guarateed if they are at all.

the file system i refer here is the extfs family.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The most definitive resource would be the kernel source code. For ext4fs, lookup is implemented in [ext4_lookup](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/fs/ext4/namei.c#L1021), and readdir in [ext4_readdir](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0.4/fs/ext4/dir.c#L111).

From a user-space perspective, the biggest difference is that lookup/traversal requires the execute permission bit, while readdir requires the read permission bit.